# Javascript parse Html tags to text

Tags: javascript, html

Let's say I get a json with property text, which contains html tags, like `<br>`.

If I print them with JavaScript the browser shows me `<br>` instead of interpreting the HTML tag.

How can I handle this problem?

Comment: How exactly are you "printing" this string? Please share with us the code you are using.

Answer (score -1):

try this: `str.replace(/</g, '\<')`
not tested.

Comment: You really should test that. It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: sorry. what I have in mind is replace all occurence of "<" to escape characters ("\<") or code (&#60;)

Comment: Under what circumstance will putting a ``\`` character in to the mix make a browser render a line break instead of showing a less than sign, a b, a r and then a greater than sign? You appear to be trying to solve the problem opposite to the one that the OP is having… for a language that isn't HTML.